# What does the verb 'wegpurzeln' mean? [context inside]

Tags: meaning-in-context, german-to-english

I am translating a Till Eulenspiegel story from German to English, and I came across the following sentence ([source link](https://www.kostenlosonlinelesen.net/kostenlose-till-eulenspiegel/lesen/4)):

> "Im nächsten Augenblick lagen beide am Boden und rangen und schlugen und kratzten sich, bis sie schließlich so übereinander **wegpurzelten**, daß sie, so wütend waren sie, sich im Dunkel überhaupt nicht wiederfanden.

Here's what I was able to understand:

> In  the next moment both were lying on the ground, wrestling, hitting and scratching each other, until in the end they __________ that, so furious they were, they could not find each other in the darkness anymore.

I looked up the bolded verb (which I assume has the infinitive form '**wegpurzeln**') in various online and offline dictionaries, but could not find a proper translation anywhere. I also looked it up on [Redensarten-index](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=wegpurzeln&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&sp0=rart_ou) which was recommended to me for idioms and such, but still nothing.

Any help would be much appreciated! The suggested translation of the entire sentence is obviously not final, as it depends on the missing part, but if you see anything else that is worth commenting on, please do!

Answer (score 20):

*wegpurzeln* is composed of *weg* (away) and [purzeln](https://www.dict.cc/?s=purzeln)

Combined with *übereinander* this translates to something alike

> until they tumbled over each other *in such a way* that they landed apart from each other

where *in such a way* is the translation for *so*, in this case.

The reason this is not showing up in a dictionary is a) it's a compound word and b) it's not super common. There are so many possibilities of compound words in German, that it's simply impracticle to list them all. Instead, if encountering one, looking for each individual word will usually give a pretty good idea about the new meaning. But we have more specific questions/answers about that on this site.

Comment: I would say: apart from each other ...

Comment: Thanks! Why, in your opinion, does that word not appear in standard dictionaries like dict.cc and the Oxford-Duden dictionary (which is pretty comprehensive)? If this question can really be answered...

Comment: It is not a super common word. Besides,  it is next to impossible to list all compound words in a dictionary. It often helps to split the verb (or word) into suffix and main verb(word) and look for the latter in your dictionary of choice. As seen above, purzeln does appear in dict.cc

Comment: ... besides of what @infinitezero said, *purzeln* is a stange word and I'm surprised, it's listed in any dictionary

Comment: The prefix weg- can be used with almost any verb indicating movement. There are other prefixes which can be used in a similar way, like davon- or herbei-. Adding all the possible combinations to a dictionary would be impractical as it would increase its size too much. One simply has to be aware of these prefixes and the possibility to create new composite verbs with them.

Comment: Thanks, that makes great sense! One follow-up question though: taking all of this into account, what does the 'so' before übereinander expresses? That they landed far apart from each other or something like that?

Comment: **so** here means **in such a way**, i.e. *until they tumbled over each other **in such a way**, that they landed apart from each other*.

Comment: Thanks, I was under the impression that the structure of 'so ... dass ...' as 'so much ... that ...' was rather solid. Thank you all for all your help! I was able to finish the story by now.

Comment: @Olafant that weg - apart contrasts with übereinander (on top of each other) to convey that sense of tumbling really the sense of opposite directions is giving this word a very dynamic tumbling sense.

Comment: @Olafant in which region is *purzeln* a strange word? In Austria,  it is quite common and frequently used in spoken language.

Comment: It's strange, really. I think "übereinander weg" should be seen together here, is it really correct that "weg" is used as a prefix to purzeln here? Would it be correct to say "übereinander weg purzeln"?

Answer (score 3):

This is a very interesting question. The verb "wegpurzeln" is not frequently used.

A google search shows that it is used as a sort of synonym for "vanish", "move away" or "roll away", especially in the context of loosing weight ("Es gibt einige Möglichkeiten und Tipps, mit denen die Pfunde schnell wegpurzeln können").

Other examples are "An unebenen Stellen könnten die Steine wegpurzeln", "aber wenn ich seh, wie meine fische wegpurzeln, wenn sie vorbeischwimmen", "Aber um mich herum sehe ich die halbwegs relevanten Blogs und Magazine in beunruhigend hoher Frequenz wegpurzeln".

In the context of your text it certainly means that they rolled away during their fight in the dark. The phrase "übereinander wegpurzelten" indicates that they moved on the ground, each of them lying alternately top and bottom, but then rolling away so that they could not find each other in the darkness anymore.

Comment: Fische purzeln wenn sie vorbeischwimmen??

Comment: @infinitezero Fundstück bei Google: https://www.aquaristik-talk.de/technik-und-wasserchemie/16766-jbl-cristalprofi-120-54-liter-becken.html . Der Text ist sicher kein Muster vorbildlichen Deutschs, aber beim Lesen stellt man fest, dass die Fische durch die Einwirkung eines Ausströmers im Aquarium "wegpurzeln".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using Kästers retelling of the "Nap in the beehive".
I agree with "tumbeling over each other" as a translation fitting. However, but would, however, suggest "tumbeling about each other" instead. The situation given in the story is quite violent and suggests that they alternately garb each other and roll around on unieven ground and try to throw each other off or down, a violent scuffle. Additional "that, so furious they were, they could not find each other in the darkness anymore." could be translated as "that - as furious as they were". Kästner seems to imply that the intensity of anger clouds their ability to find each other again in the dark. The other reading would be open to the interpretation that they could find each other although they were very angry and wanted to fight.